# How to sort the coordinates and variables of an xr.Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I would like to sort the coordinates and variables of an xarray `Dataset` in alphabetical order. I have tried to do this using `ds.transpose(*sorted(ds.dims))`. This seems to sort the coordinates/dimensions of each `DataArray` in the `Dataset`, but not the coordinates of the `Dataset` itself.

Example:

```py
>>> ds = xr.Dataset(
...     {
...         'z': (['c', 'a', 'b'], np.ones(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
...         'x': (['a', 'b', 'c'], np.zeros(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
...         'y': (['c'], [0, 1]),
...     },
...     coords={'c': [30, 31], 'a': [10, 11], 'b': [20, 21]}
... )
    
>>> ds.transpose('a', 'b', 'c')
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (c: 2, a: 2, b: 2)
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 30 31
  * a        (a) int64 10 11
  * b        (b) int64 20 21
Data variables:
    z        (a, b, c) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    x        (a, b, c) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    y        (c) int64 0 1
```

Expected behaviour is that the coordinates and dimensions of the entire `xr.Dataset` would be sorted as `'a', 'b', 'c'`. However, you can see that only the dimensions of the data variables themselves are in this order.

How can I sort the coordinates and variables of a Dataset, not just the array dimensions?

Any help is deeply appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The code you provided does not work. You should create a so called [MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: works just fine for me. unless the indent threw you off?

Comment: updated code block formatting. @Pedro this runs for me out of the box with xarray 0.19.0 and numpy 1.20.3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in xarray with `xr.Dataset.reindex_like` and `xr.Dataset.reindex`. The former is helpful if you have another object that you want to match.

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
data_vars={
'z': (['c', 'a', 'b'], np.ones(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
'x': (['a', 'b', 'c'], np.zeros(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
'y': (['c'], [0, 1]),
},
coords={'c': [30, 31], 'a': [10, 11], 'b': [20, 21]}
)

current_indexes = ds.indexes
desired_order = ['a', 'b', 'c']
reordered_indexes = {index_name: current_indexes[index_name] for index_name in desired_order}
reordered_ds = ds.reindex(reordered_indexes)
```

```
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (c: 2, a: 2, b: 2)
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 30 31
  * a        (a) int64 10 11
  * b        (b) int64 20 21
Data variables:
    z        (c, a, b) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    x        (a, b, c) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    y        (c) int64 0 1
>>> reordered_ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2, b: 2, c: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 10 11
  * b        (b) int64 20 21
  * c        (c) int64 30 31
Data variables:
    z        (c, a, b) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    x        (a, b, c) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    y        (c) int64 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
data_vars={
'z': (['c', 'a', 'b'], np.ones(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
'x': (['a', 'b', 'c'], np.zeros(shape=(2, 2, 2))),
'y': (['c'], [0, 1]),
},
coords={'c': [30, 31], 'a': [10, 11], 'b': [20, 21]}
)


df = ds.to_dataframe()
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
print(df.to_xarray())

# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:  (a: 2, b: 2, c: 2)
# Coordinates:
#   * a        (a) int64 10 11
#   * b        (b) int64 20 21
#   * c        (c) int64 30 31
# Data variables:
#     x        (a, b, c) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
#     y        (a, b, c) int32 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
#     z        (a, b, c) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: thanks. an answer that uses xarray natively would be preferable if possible!

Comment: Yea, tried but; i cant make it :)