# How to change the order in dimensions xarray.Dataset?

Tags: dataset, python-xarray, dimensions

I am creating a xarray dataset as below:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x_example = np.random.rand(1488,)
y_example = np.random.rand(1331,)
time_example = np.random.rand(120,)
rainfall_example = np.random.rand(120, 1331, 1488)

rainfall_dataset = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        rainfall_depth=(['time', 'y', 'x'], rainfall_example),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        time=(['time'], time_example),
        x=(['x'], x_example),
        y=(['y'], y_example)
    )
)
```

The results are like this

[image]

And the dimensions when I run `rainfall_example.dims` are like this `Frozen({'time': 120, 'y': 1331, 'x': 1488})` (this can also be seen in the above results). I know the `xarray.Dataset.dims` cannot be modified according to [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.dims.html)

My question is: How can we change the order of those dimensions into the dimensions like this `Frozen({'time': 120, 'x': 1488, 'y': 1331})` without changing anything else (everything will be the same only the order in dimensions is changed)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69745106/how-to-sort-the-coordinates-and-variables-of-an-xr-dataset?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

You can reorder your coordinates and variables by selecting them both in order using a list:

```py
In [3]: rainfall_dataset[["time", "y", "x", "rainfall_depth"]]
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (time: 120, y: 1331, x: 1488)
Coordinates:
  * time            (time) float64 0.2848 0.7556 0.9501 ... 0.694 0.734 0.198
  * y               (y) float64 0.1941 0.1132 0.2504 ... 0.1501 0.5085 0.006135
  * x               (x) float64 0.2776 0.4504 0.1886 ... 0.4071 0.3327 0.5555
Data variables:
    rainfall_depth  (time, y, x) float64 ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, this way will change the shape of my ```rainfall_depth``` variable (from ```(time, y, x)``` to ```(time, x, y)```), so it does not work for me unfortunately. As I mentioned, I wish to keep everything the same, only the order of in dimensions is changed.

Comment: So sorry - I misread your question. Does simply calling transpose work?

Comment: Or perhaps transpose, followed by re-ordering the coordinates back to the original using this list method I describe?

Comment: Do you mean this ```rainfall_dataset.transpose()```? If it is, it did not work either. It still changes the shape of my ```rainfall_depth``` variable and the order of dimensions are still the same.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I don’t understand your question. Can you describe exactly what you want as a result?

Comment: It actually works when I tried as you suggested re-ordering the coordinates ```rainfall_dataset.transpose("time", "y", "x")[["time", "x", "y", "rainfall_depth"]]```. And this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much @Michael. If it's possible, you can change the answer and then I will upvote for it.

Comment: Got it. Then you don’t actually need the transpose. Updated my answer.

Comment: For some reason this seems to drop all the data variables out of my dataset...

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn’t! Feel free to ask another question and post your code and results if you don’t figure it out